# Installing OpenEdge driver on Sql Server Cluster

Tags: sql-server, database, progress-4gl, openedge

I have a SQL Server 2005 64-bit cluster, and I need to import from a Progress DB frequently.  I tried installing the Progress Openedge 10.0B driver on each VM in the cluster, but after I enter the serial number and CD key, select "Client networking", and click "Next", the setup freezes then has to be closed because of Not Responding.

Is there a standar way to deploy a driver like this to a cluster?  I've already installed msdasql on both VMs, so I assumed it'd be a similar process.  The openedge driver is 32-bit, but it's installed fine on a SQL server 2012 that was 64-bit.

If there's another way to easily transfer the data between SQL server and Progress/OpenEdge/QAD, please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Check with Progress Support. [http://www.progress.com](http://www.progress.com). Given that 10.0B is several years old and retired they will likely recommend an upgrade.

Comment: Progress also has a "Dataserver" product which supports connecting an OpenEdge client to a SQL Server engine.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was trying to install the driver off a shared drive on a virtual machine.  I had the same problem on other machines, and the only thing they had in common was the virtual machine status.

Once I copied the install files to each machine's local drive, everything installed fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if isdel.exe is running.  If it is, kill it.  It seems to be chicken soup for hung Progress installs.